# Spring - complete shutdown of web application

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application which I'm trying to shut down by executing the `close()` method on the context:

```
((ConfigurableApplicationContext) appContext).close();
```

After executing this the application appears to be continuing running, health page produces the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
```

Is there a way to shudown the whole thing via Spring or should I resort to `System.exit()`?

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Comment: You should almost never use `System.exit()`. It sounds like you're running the application inside a traditional container instead of using a Spring Boot embedded container. In that case, you'll need to use the container's shutdown command.

Comment: @chrylis yep agree `System.exit()`.  I am running the application in traditional in traditional servlet container.  Would there be a way to send the shutdown command to tomcat or jetty from my Spring application programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'd have to be able to get access to the management interface, or to do something like run `tomcat stop` as a process. Is migrating to an embedded servlet container an option? It sounds like your container is a single-application container anyway.

Comment: It is a option but quite interested to find out if there is a possibility to do that without switching going embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease have a look at these questions. They are on the same line as yours:
[How to manage Tomcat via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046436/how-to-manage-tomcat-via-java),
[Start / stop a web application from itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987583/start-stop-a-web-application-from-itself)

As @chrylis suggested, I think the easiest way of shutting down the server(if it's not running in embedded mode) is to use Runtime class.