# Java : Reload webapp in the servlet and then redirect request

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, httprequest

I have a configuration page in my app. When user changes configuration and submits it, I would like to reload my application with new configuration properties and then redirect to some page. I was able to reload my application using some suggestions I found here 
[Start / stop a web application from itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987583/start-stop-a-web-application-from-itself)

but I am not able to redirect to new page after the application has reloaded.

More details.

```
public class ConfigurationServlet extends HttpServlet implements ContainerServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SalsaEnvironment salsaEnv;
    protected Host host = null;
    protected Wrapper wrapper = null;
    protected Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // update configuration properties
        .
        .
        . 

        // reload app once configuration is changed
        restartWebApp(resp.getWriter(), "/salsadb");

        // simple redirect/forward - does not work - gives following exception
        // java.lang.NullPointerException org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        //resp.sendRedirect("/salsadb/account");
        //req.getRequestDispatcher("/account");

        // invalid old session, create a new one and try to redirect - does not work
        req.getSession(false).invalidate();
        req.getSession(true);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/account");
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper getWrapper() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWrapper(Wrapper wrapper) {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        if (wrapper == null) {
            context = null;
            host = null;
        } else {
            context = (Context) wrapper.getParent();
            host = (Host) context.getParent();
            Engine engine = (Engine) host.getParent();
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ?
            }
        }
    }

    private void restartWebApp(PrintWriter writer, String path){
        if ((path == null) || (!path.startsWith("/") && path.equals(""))) {
            System.out.println("invalid path");
            return;
        }
        String displayPath = path;
        if( path.equals("/") )
            path = "";

        try {
            Context context = (Context) host.findChild(path);
            if (context == null) {
                /*writer.println(sm.getString
                               ("managerServlet.noContext",
                                   RequestUtil.filter(displayPath)));*/
                System.out.println("no context");
                return;
            }

            context.reload();
            //writer.println(sm.getString("managerServlet.reloaded", displayPath));
            System.out.println("reloaded webapp");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log("ManagerServlet.reload[" + displayPath + "]", t);
            /*writer.println(sm.getString("managerServlet.exception",
                                        t.toString()));*/
            System.out.println("excpetion during reloading the webapp");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you reloading the webapp just for properties change ? If so, you can change properties at runtime without reloading the webapp. (EDIT : it's not OOTB and need a bit of work but might be more efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably not be able to do that as your **server-side code** has just been *restarted*.

I'd recommend an **AJAX** based client-side approach, where you constantly ping some servlet of yours until app is "back up" and then move to the new page via JavaScript.

For this to work, you'd **first** send the redirect to the reload-checking page and **then** (say after 1s to allow the browser fetch the redirected page) initiate the restart:

```
    req.getSession(false).invalidate();
    req.getSession(true);
    resp.sendRedirect("check_restart_status.jsp");
    //Use a timer or whatever
    new Thread(() -> {
        try{
          Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
          return;
        }
        restartWebApp("/salsadb");
    }).start();
```

Comment: Problem is that the browser immediately shows an error page after request is handled in my servlet. I don't want to show an error page to the user.

Comment: See my edit: You give the browser time to load the "wait for restart" page and THEN initiate the actual restart.